# Infobox display on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I've searched for 3 hours now and cant find a solution. All im after is when you click on an input field in a form, an infobox at the side reveals itself. I tried messing about with jQuery and just couldnt get it to work even though im sure the code is correct (aren't we always lol).

Anyway id appreciate any solution.

My attempt at jquery/css/html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .infoBubble {
        visibility:hidden;
        color:#000;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.box').click(function () { 
        $('.infoBubble').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="process.php" method="get">

            <div class="row">
                <span class="label">Description: </span> 
                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="box" /><span class="infoBubble">Specific information related to this input</span>
            </div>

        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your JavaScript is being executed before the document has finished loading, meaning the input field does not exist. Attach your code to jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event to prevent this from happening.

```
$(function() {
    $('.box').click(function () { 
        $('.infoBubble').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    });
}
```

Secondly, an element hidden with `visiblity: hidden` will still take up space in the layout. Usually you would use `display: none` to make it seem as if the element were not there at all. Either way, you can use the [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method to make the element visible.

CSS:

```
.infoBubble {
    color: #000;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.infoBubble').show();
```

Thirdly, it is possible that your users focus the input without clicking on it (e.g., by pressing tab)! By using the [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) event instead of `click` you can show the message regardless.

```
$('.box').focus(function() { 
    $('.infoBubble').show()
});
```

In addition to the above, you can also use the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event to hide the message when the user no longer has focus on the input (when they click elsewhere, or tabbing out of it). All together you end up with something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.box').focus(function() {
        $('.infoBubble').show();
    }).blur(function() {
        $('.infoBubble').hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Is that the code for the ready event? Based on your answer i found this and it worked so thanks for your reply. $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: @user29660: `$(function() {` is the shorthand version of `$(document).ready(function() {`. Both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.box').click(function (){
    $('.infoBubble').toggle();
});
```

By the way. The css-property to hide/show something is not `visibility`, but `display`. For example:

```
display: none;
```

or

```
display: block;
```

Comment: visibility is valid. `visibility: hidden` hides an element but does not remove it from the flow of the document. `display: none` hides an element and removes it from the page flow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: visibilty is used when the property remains on the page taking up the same spacing and position but isnt visible. Display removes it completely.